# MySql Update first entry that has X and Y else insert new record

Tags: mysql, database, syntax, insert, sql-update

I have a chat user entry in a MySql table -

id (primary key, autoincrement) - the chat user id
user_id - the users id as it pertains to our product
room_id - the id of the room your in

If a chat operator enters the room, leaves, and then comes back - as it is now - will create two entries in the room (INSERT INTO chatuser ...)

I know INSERT IF NOT EXISTS syntax, however I want to IF NOT EXISTS not on the primary key, but WHERE user_id = x AND room_id = y (which will be the same if they re-enter a room they have been in)

something like INSERT INTO chatuser SET user_id=4, room_id=2 IF ENTRY DOESNT EXIST WITH THOSE VALUES ALREADY ;)

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a unique index on (user_id,room_id), you can do `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (or `INSERT IGNORE` if you don't need to update anything when the record already exists):

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (user_id, room_id, enter_date)
VALUES  (1,1, NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
enter_date = NOW()

// or
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_1 (user_id, room_id)
VALUES (1,1)
```

Comment: user_id and room_id are unique, in seperate tables. the chatuser table has no notion of this. in theory though, each user_id + room_id combo should be unique in the chatuser table, though as it is the INSERT will create two entries with user_id and room_id the same

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If room_id + user_id should be unique, then add a unique index to your table :`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_Uid_RId ON table_1(user_id,room_id)`

Answer (score 0):

I think what we have here is a design issue. You have 3 tables, a user table, a room table and a table that links that two. The last one is what we're working with here. Now, if you want to log every time a user enters a room, the table design you have is ideal. However it seems that is not what you are doing. It seems you want an entry for just the last visit. In this case your table should not have an auto incrementing primary key, and instead should have userID and roomID to both be parts of a multi-column primary key.

Modify your table to that set-up then run your insert statement with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause.